# Date/Time Field In Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have the following code in php that inserts a start date and end date with the date and time .  The date and time is added via the iphone date and time wheel when selecting the input field.  The problem however is that if I select 1pm local time as the start date and 2pm as the end date it will submit the record as 6pm and 7pm.  Is this a coding issue, a date/time field issue or a form issue? The variables of $start_date and $end_date are pulled directly from the input form.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO events (event_id, event_name, user_name, id_user, start_date, end_date, details, location, dresscode,private) VALUES ('NULL', '".$event_name."', '".$user_name."', '".$user_id."', '".$start_date."','".$end_date."','".$time."','".$location."','".$dresscode."','".$private_id."')";
mysql_query ($query);
```

Comment: What is the field type of your start and end date columns?

Comment: datetime in mysql, type="datetime" in html

Comment: What time zone are you in? It sounds like it's submitting it in UTC.

Comment: The date getting converted to UTC would be correct. Mysql will do this for timestamp columns automatically based on the system or connection timezone, but not for datetime columns. It sounds like its originating from the form.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the form? The field is an input with a type="datetime"

Comment: @datasage it is the form, I echo'd the input field before insert and it was pushed ahead 5 hours.  any idea what could be wrong with the input field?

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I figured out the problem on the form.  If anyone ever needs this for future use.  If you set the type="datetime-local" it will disregard timezones and use your local time.